# Casting from derived type to base type

Tags: c#, oop, nhibernate

Given that

```
public abstract class AbstractOrder
{
    //some properties...
}

public class AnonymousOrder:AbstractOrder
{
    //some properties...
}


public class PartnerOrder:AbstractOrder
    {
        //some properties...
    }


public AbstractOrder FindOrderByConfirmationNumber(string confirmationNumber)
{
    ICriteria criteria =
        Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(AbstractOrder))
            .SetMaxResults(10)
            .AddOrder(Order.Desc("PurchasedDate"))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ConfirmationNumber", confirmationNumber));
    var l = criteria.List<AbstractOrder>();
    AbstractOrder ao = l[0] as AbstractOrder;
    return ao as AbstractOrder;
}
```

Can someone please explain why

```
PartnerOrder order = repo.FindOrderByConfirmationNumber(confirmationNumber)
```

returns a type of AnonymousOrder and how I get it to return a type of PartnerOrder?

Comment: how do you know *returns a type of AnonymousOrder *? Your code actually work correctly

Comment: What is the result of typeof(order).Name?

Comment: you want it to return an abstract type?
use it like AbstractOrder, you don't need to cast it,
as long as your derivate class follows the contract it should work ;)

Comment: Yeah, you're not telling us something.  Your code, as currently written, cannot possibly know anything about `AnonymousOrder`.

Comment: I know it is AbstractOrder by stepping thru it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FindOrder *is* returning a type of `AbstractOrder`; just look at its declaration.  The *object* it returns may be an instance of `AnonymousOrder`, but all `AnonymousOrder` instances are also `AbstractOrder` instances, because `AnonymousOrder` inherits from `AbstractOrder`.

I think your real problem is trying to assign an `AnonymousOrder` instance to a `PartnerOrder` reference.  This won't work, since neither type is derived from the other.

This, however, will work:

```
AnonymousOrder order = (AnonymousOrder)repo.FindOrderByConfirmationNumber(confirmationNumber);
```

Alternatively, you could test the type of the return value:

```
AbstractOrder order = repo.FindOrderByConfirmationNumber(confirmationNumber);
PartnerOrder partnerOrder = order as PartnerOrder;
if (partnerOrder != null)
    //...
```

If you really need a PartnerOrder instance for a confirmationNumber that returns an AnonymousOrder, then you'll need a method that takes an AnonymousOrder instance and returns a PartnerOrder instance.  Or, perhaps, you should rethink your design.

Comment: Thanks - I would LOVE to rethink the design but I don't have that option so I'll go with a method to map the two

Answer (score 1):

AbstractOrder is an Abstract class. No object can ONLY be an abstract class, it can inherit from it as a base class but it is always something else as well.

It's returning type AnonymousOrder which is the most specific class it is, but it also an AbstractOrder. You can treat it as just an AbstractOrder, nothing should be effected.

Comment: Thanks - so how do I cast it as a PartnerOrder - When I try it fails with Unable to cast object of type 'AnonymousOrder' to type 'PartnerOrder'.